# cryptoprevent whitelist spotify

Tags: powershell, spotify, whitelist

I am trying to execute this code:

```
$username = "$env:username"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foolish IT\CryptoPrevent\cryptoprevent.exe" /apply /appdata /silent /a=C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spotify.exe,/a=C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spwebinst0.exe,/a=C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spotifylauncher.exe
```

However the Cryptoprevent command line cannot recognize the variable.  Running the above command whitelists.  c:\users\$username\appdata ....

I need to get the current logged in user and then build the code with the actual username already in the command then execute it.

Comment: As written, no command would execute at all, because `"..."` at the start of a command line is interpreted as a _string to output_. If you got past that with `& `, however, then `$username` _would_ be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell isn't expanding the variable as it's not treating that part of your command as a string.

You can use `Start-Process` with `ArgumentList` to make this happen:

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foolish IT\CryptoPrevent\cryptoprevent.exe" -ArgumentList "/apply","/appdata","/silent","/a=C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spotify.exe,/a=C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spwebinst0.exe,/a=C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spotifylauncher.exe"
```

I would use `$env:appdata` directly as this is the `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming` folder.

```
$CryptoPreventPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foolish IT\CryptoPrevent\cryptoprevent.exe"

$args = @(
    "/apply",
    "/appdata",
    "/silent",
    "/a=$env:appdata\Spotify\spotify.exe,/a=$env:appdata\Spotify\spwebinst0.exe,/a=$env:appdata\Spotify\spotifylauncher.exe"
)

Start-Process $CryptoPreventPath -ArgumentList $args
```

Comment: Good tip re `$env:APPDATA`, but there's no need for `Start-Process` - `&` is all that is needed. If you use `Start-Process`, the invocation becomes asynchronous; while you could fix that with `-Wait`, the process would be disconnected from the output streams of the calling session. In short: there's no good reason to use `Start-Process` for synchronous invocation of a console app.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute an external program (or any command, for that matter) whose name or path is:

- enclosed in single or double *quotes*
- or stored in a *variable*

you must use `&`, the *call operator* to invoke it.

Therefore:

```
$username = $env:username
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foolish IT\CryptoPrevent\cryptoprevent.exe" /apply /appdata /silent /a=C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spotify.exe,/a=C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spwebinst0.exe,/a=C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\spotifylauncher.exe
```

A few asides:

- There's no reason to enclose `$env:username` in `"..."`; furthermore, you could just reference `$env:username` *directly* in your command.
- Going further, as [James C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2208505/james-c) points out, you could replace `C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming` with simply `$env:APPDATA`.